Use OpenVPN /dev/net/tun from an LXC in other LXCs
In proxmox I have passed /dev/net/tun to a LXC with debian than just runs openvpn.
To pass the tun I add to /etc/pve/lxc/XXX.conf
lxc.cgroup2.devices.allow: c 10:200 rwm
lxc.mount.entry: /dev/net dev/net none bind,create=dir
lxc.mount.entry: /dev/net/tun dev/net/tun none bind,create=file

It's running and connected to my VPN provider.
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.24.19.21/24 brd 10.24.19.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::aa4:4842:8f62:661f/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I assume that after having openvpn running I could just pass the tun to other LXC, for example qbittorrent, and select tun0 as the interface for connections.
But I only see lo and eth0.
How am I supposed to do this?
Edit:
I could not figure this out so here's what I did.
I installed a OPNsense LXC
I created a Wireguard Connection using PIA (I used FingerlessGlov3s' script)
Those LXCs I want routed through WG I add their IP to Firewall ‣ Aliases and then set OPNsense's IP as that LXC gateway.
Now, this is using Wireguard, not OpenVPN, but I assume a similar setup can be made by following the script as a guide

Network interfaces do not appear in /dev. Is there any particular reason you want OpenVPN running in a different container?

I will probably use it in more than qbittorrent, so I don´t want to set it up in every LXC that needs it

Did you find a solution to this?

Pretty sure I didn't, all this is on hold but I moved to using a OPNsense LXC
